# how to check if a user is logged in using chrome identity api?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, google-oauth

I am trying to add authentication to my chrome extension and I am using chrome identity-api for that. I am using the getAuthToken API for fetching the access token. I want to provide login/logout functionality in my popup.html such that login button is displayed only when the user is not logged in (or logged out). However, I am not able to figure out a way to check if the user is logged in or not.

Comment: Did you figure a way to do this? I am stuck at the same problem.

Comment: @Kanishka you need most probably to draw it down. In most cases you have a corresponding user in your backend and just check if there's a sessionId set with the backend. If not, you just assume user is logged out and just go through the whole process again; 1) sign in Google, 2) exchange Identity Token retrieved from Google with a sessionId from your backend. And that's it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check `chrome.runtime.lastError`

I'm doing this using `interactive: false` when my popup loads.

If the user isn't logged in, the call to `getAuthToken` will fail and my function will return.  If the user is logged in, I display a logged in element and display a logout button.

If a user isn't logged in, I have a sign in with google button for them to click.

```
window.onload = () => {
  console.log("starting popup.js");

  chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ interactive: false }, function (token) {
    // If the user isn't logged in yet, make them login via clicking button
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
      // Something went wrong
      console.warn("Whoops.. " + chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
      // Maybe explain that to the user too?
      return;
    }
    document.getElementById("logged-in").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("btn-logout").disabled = false;

};
```